# Validation of dates based on the user inputs

Tags: php, function, datepicker

Given the Following code,how can I trap a function where in it would only allow a user a certain range of date to choose from the datepicker.

Ex.

If the user chooses the **Monthly** on the dropdown, it would only allow the user a range of **28 days**. if the user chooses a **Weekly**, the system would only allow **5 days**, and **Daily** for only **2days**...

Scenario1:

```
Date from: 2011-09-01
Date to: 2011-09-31

Result: (prompt) you are only allowed to input within 28 days.
```

Scenario2:

```
Date from: 2011-09-01
Date to: 2011-09-20

Result: it will proceed to another page.
```

If the user chooses an  invalid selection, the system will prompt.

Thanks in advance.

```
<select size="1" name="duration" id="duration" style="position:relative; top:-212px;     left:-440px; width:100px;">
                <option value="0">Monthly</option>
                <option value="1">Weekly</option>
                <option value="2">Daily</option>
            </select>
        </dd>
    </dl>

                <dl>
                    <dt style="float:left;"><label for="fname" id = "label">Date From:</label></dt>
                    <dd><input type="text" name="timestamp" id="calendar1" class="calendarFocus" size="54"/>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
              <dl>
                    <dt style="float:left;"><label for="fname" id ="label">Date To:</label></dt>
                    <dd><input type="text" name="timestamp1" id="calendar2" class="calendarFocus" size="54"/> 
                </dd>
                </dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onchange` event call to a Javascript function with your business logic.

`<select onchange="callYourFunction(this)" ...>`

In the function you would then do something like this:

`<script type="text/javascript">
 function callYourFunction(oe) {`

The Javascript function would then check the value of the select dropdown (`oe` is the object), and prompt using `alerts()`.

Comment: Sir, what do you mean 'object' in your oe? can you give me the exact form of code based on what you said? thanks..